# Mysql Workbench - Error processing forward engineering

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I want to raise a small problem MySQL Workbench, but first of all I want you to know that this question previously made, but without much explanation and a lot of code that leaves many questions, and as I have not been to find the problem, the question will easy and explanatory possible.

**1)** I made a simple model in MySQL Workbench, a relationship between two tables.

If I make the execution "Forward engineering" of this model is created without problem.

But the problem it is following...

**The code that generates me MySQL Workbench:**

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema example
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema example
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `example` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `example` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `example`.`status`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example`.`status` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `create_at` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `example`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example`.`users` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `create_at` DATETIME NULL,
  `status_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_users_status_idx` (`status_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_status`
    FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`)
    REFERENCES `example`.`status` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

**2)** I need to make an optimization to the table **status**, and I will make a simple change because the status.id only have a maximum of 10 records, and the data type **INT** **id** field think it's too big for this then what I would do is change **id INT** to **id TINYINT**

I made this simple change and stuck:

**The code that generates me MySQL Workbench:**

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema example
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema example
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `example` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `example` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `example`.`status`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example`.`status` (
  `id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `create_at` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `example`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example`.`users` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `create_at` DATETIME NULL,
  `status_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_users_status_idx` (`status_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_status`
    FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`)
    REFERENCES `example`.`status` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

**Error:** If I make the execution "Forward engineering" of this model it shows me the following error:

*I would greatly appreciate your help, thank you very much.*

Comment: Did you also attempt to alter your users role_id to TINYINT?

Comment: I'm changing the data type of the field ID of the role table, if there are record in the role table, these records will be maintained with their values. The idea of this is to optimize this role table, the table that roles will be a maximum of 15 records. "Mysql says on its official website that TINYINT accepts a maximum of 127 or unsigned and weighs 1 byte however the INT data type supports a maximum of 2147483647 and weighs 4 bytes, I think it's more optimal use TINYINT in this table.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want the role_id column in the users table to remain as INT, as opposed to TINYINT?

Comment: Knowing some reason, that would consume unnecessary space in the web of Mysq are examples, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html, but remember this e sun simple example to view the problem and solution.

Comment: The FK and PK should have the same data type. You have two different types; INT and TINYINT. Choose one. :)

Comment: @Philip Olson, thank you very much, problem solved, question, is there any way to do this Workbench automatically, because here I can see that is very easy to see the error, but what if modeling is a very big thing, eg about 45 tables, it would be very cumbersome to do this manually.